# Which class has the implementation of the getSession() method?

Tags: servlets

I am a little confused about the various methods' implementations. 
 Actually, I was Learning Servlet and JSP and I found many methods like

```
request.getSession(); 
response.getWriter();
```

so please, can any one tell me where (In which class) the implementation of the methods (`getSession()`, `getWriter()`, etc) are present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are present in the servletcontainer itself. Even more, the servletcontainer is at its own actually the whole concrete implementation of the Servlet API.

In case of [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) (which is [open source](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)), the implementation of `request.getSession()` is provided by the [`org.apache.catalina.connector.Request`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.html) class. In the current Tomcat 7.0.25 release it look like this:

```
2288    @Override
2289    public HttpSession getSession() {
2290        Session session = doGetSession(true);
2291        if (session == null) {
2292            return null;
2293        }
2294
2295        return session.getSession();
2296    }
```

Equivalently, the `response.getWriter()` implementation is provided by [`org.apache.catalina.connector.Response`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.html) class which look like this in Tomcat 7.0.25:

```
628    @Override
629    public PrintWriter getWriter()
630        throws IOException {
631
632        if (usingOutputStream) {
633            throw new IllegalStateException
634                (sm.getString("coyoteResponse.getWriter.ise"));
635        }
636
637        if (ENFORCE_ENCODING_IN_GET_WRITER) {
638            /*
639             * If the response's character encoding has not been specified as
640             * described in <code>getCharacterEncoding</code> (i.e., the method
641             * just returns the default value <code>ISO-8859-1</code>),
642             * <code>getWriter</code> updates it to <code>ISO-8859-1</code>
643             * (with the effect that a subsequent call to getContentType() will
644             * include a charset=ISO-8859-1 component which will also be
645             * reflected in the Content-Type response header, thereby satisfying
646             * the Servlet spec requirement that containers must communicate the
647             * character encoding used for the servlet response's writer to the
648             * client).
649             */
650            setCharacterEncoding(getCharacterEncoding());
651        }
652
653        usingWriter = true;
654        outputBuffer.checkConverter();
655        if (writer == null) {
656            writer = new CoyoteWriter(outputBuffer);
657        }
658        return writer;
659
660    }
```

So has each other servletcontainer/appserver ([Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net), [JBoss AS](http://jboss.org/jbossas), [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), [WebLogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/index.html), [WebSphere AS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/), etc) its own implementation (although they mostly use a fork of Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) has the implementations of [`getSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) you'll be interested in, implemented by [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) and its parent [`SerlvetRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html).

Unsurprisingly, [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) is the starting point for `getWriter()`, but the implementation lives in [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) (actually in its superclass, [`ServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html)).

This should all be searchable, however: you call those from servlets. If you call them, you've imported them. If you've imported them, you have the fully-qualified class name. If you have the FQN you can look up the class's Javadocs. If you have the Javadocs, you have links to superclasses/interfaces.

Comment: Wrappers are not the implementations... They just by default delegate all methods to the wrapped instance as passed during their construction (as per the decorator pattern; so that the developer doesn't need to repeat all the countless methods which the developer doesn't need to override).